# PUSH/POP equivalents in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

what exactly are the PUSH/POP equivalentes for ARM Assembly? Do I need to use STR/LDR with SP? My professor told us to run this code on ARM SIM, but apparently this code belongs to an older processor, like Intel 8088, I suppose:

```
      MOV sp, #801
      MOV r1, #25
      MOV r2, #10
      PUSH {r2}
      BL SUB1
      POP {r2}

SUB1: POP {r0}
      POP {r3}
      PUSH {r1}
      ADD r1, r1, r1
      ADD r3, r1, r3
      POP {r1}
      PUSH {r3}
      PUSH {r0}
      BX lr
```

Actually, instead of BL and BX, the code originally had CALL and RTS, but I tried to adapt to ARM Assembly myself, but I stopped at PUSH/POP instructions.

Comment: You might want to find a few more relevant tags to get more visibility for the question.

Comment: Which ARM architecture? (ARMv5, ARMv7, ...)

Comment: Use stmdb sp!,{r2} for push {r2}, and ldmia sp!,{r2} for pop {r2}. (stmdb - store multiple, decrement before, ldmia - load multiple, increment after). For sub1, use ldmia sp!,{r0,r3} and stmdb sp!,{r0,r3} . Some ARM assemblers have push and pop macros.

Comment: As well as depending on what extensions your particular tools offer as rcgldr says, it can also depend on what exactly you're targeting - `push` and `pop` are real instructions in Thumb, and in the post-ARMv6 Unified Assembly Language are architecturally-defined aliases for `stmdb`/`str` and `ldmia`/`ldr` (as appropriate) in ARM state.

Comment: even if you dont use unified in gnu assembler, I think it lets you use push and pop for arm instructions and just replaces it with the appropriate stm/str/ldm/ldr